# Multiple images per post - Show random image elsewhere

Tags: plugins, images, loop

I'm after either a plugin suggestion or code suggestion that best handles images per post. Here's the scenario, every post could have up to 6 images, all to be assigned class names etc.  All to be displayed on single.php. I'd like to be able to choose one of those 6 images that I'd like to display as a large image within the same template file.

Additionally, out of these 6 images I'd like to randomly call in 1 random one on to a custom page template in another loop elsewhere on the site.

To a novice like myself, this seems pretty complex and I wouldn't know where to start. How would I go about managing this? Is there a plugin that allows this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to choose one of those 6 images that I'd like to display as a large image within the same template file.

This would probably fit as [the Post Thumbnail/Post Featured Image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

> Additionally, out of these 6 images I'd like to randomly call in 1 random one on to a custom page template in another loop elsewhere on the site.

Try using [**`get_children()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) with the `'orderby' => 'rand'` and `'numberposts' => 1` parameters.

Assuming you know how to get the ID of the post whose image attachments you want to display, as `$post_id`:

```
$random_post_images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => $post_id,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment'
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'numberposts'    => 1,
) );
```

This will return an array of one image, as an object:

```
$random_post_image_object = $random_post_images[0];
```

Now, you can output the image, using [**`wp_get_attachment_image()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image):

```
$random_post_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $random_post_image_object->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: So, how do I add these 6 images to the post itself via the editing post page? Do I just click on the 'Upload media' button? Sorry, another question, how would I output all 6 images wrapped around a div on the single.php template?

Comment: You need to split separate questions into separate posts. One post: one question. :)

Comment: But in answer to your question: **yes**. You upload/attach images directly to the post, via the edit-post page.

Comment: But in order to fully understand the solution I need to ask more questions. Will this work for pages too? ;)

Comment: Yes, this will work for pages. Both blog posts and static pages support attachment post types.

Comment: Its just breaking the page at the moment, I think i'm missing something. This is my code within the loop on a custom page template: http://pastebin.com/L6kBGmQa

Comment: Where are you defining `$post_id`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to if i'm being honest so at the moment I'm not. How do I do it? I appreciate your time in helping me :)

Comment: That's nearly impossible for me to answer without more information: how do you determine the post or posts for which you want to show a random image?

Comment: Well this is my entire loop for index.php and this is where I want the random image code to go...http://pastebin.com/UCD1rY3x Does this help towards answering your question? Sorry I can't be of more use :(

Comment: Can you describe in *human terms* how you want to determine the posts for which you want to display a random image?

Comment: Its okay I spotted a similar code snippet to yours elsewhere, spotted where I was going wrong & I've now got it working. Thanks for your patience.